# Why does sample function return same set of random numbers during 1st two iteration of loop?

Tags: python, iteration, sample

```
exp = []
for i in range(0,2):
    exp.append(sample_data.sample(n=5))
    print(exp)
```

Below output shows two same set of random numbers generated and third time, numbers changed.
Output - [image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 3):

I conducted research on this `sample()` and came to conclusion that the function selects random values from series, but it also generates multiple same set of values when run inside loops. It has no control over checking if multiple same sets of values are generated at different iteration turn. For example :-
On iteration count 1 it will generate random set of values of predefined length i.e Sample(n=5) -> (4,1,6,2,8)
On iteration count 2 it can generate same random set of values generated during iteration 1. -> (4,1,6,2,8)

`sample()` only checks for unique values being generated at that particular iteration and don't store or compare those generated values with set of values generated at different iteration counts.

Comment: Please format the answer as per SO community guidelines.